# how to get wifi information in angualr js browser application?

Tags: angularjs

Do we have any network APIs which we can use in angularjs framework to get wifi information? or is it possible to get with windows object ?
Can any suggest to me if there is any such API's? so I can go ahead with further implementation

Comment: It seems highly unlikely such a interface exists. That's personal system information that a website should really never need to know.

Comment: yeah, but the requirement is to warn the user if he is connected to the insecure network and tries to access our application, so is there a way to do so? I understand this is something possible with android apps but is it possible in browser applications?

Comment: Do you want to check if your web app is connected to wifi or something else? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection .